# Animation for Android Keyboard dismiss (React-native)

Tags: animation, react-native, keyboard

I am completely new to React-Native. I'm using dismissKeyboard from 'react-native-dismiss-keyboard. The issue is when 'dismissKeyboard()' is invoked, the keyboard is disappearing rapidly. Instead, I am looking for having an animation for 500 ms.

I have also tried 'react-native keyboard' and 'react-native-keyboard-spacer', but no luck, especially for Android.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

**-- Updated (example code) --**

```
`import KeyboardSpacer from 'react-native-keyboard-spacer';
 import { AppRegistry, Text, View, TextInput} from 'react-native';`

 'return (
   <TextInput style={{left: 0, right: 0, height: 45, borderWidth:1}}
   placeholder={'Default text'}/>
   <KeyboardSpacer />
 );`
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, can you share some code and show us your work?

Comment: @PawelGradecki - I have provided the code.

Answer (score 0):

According to current documentation, [Keybard RN Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard.html), would be something like this:

```
 <TextInput
    onSubmitEditing={Keyboard.dismiss}
  />
```

Just use **Keyboard.dismiss** whatever you want.

Works like a charm to me.

Check it out on documentation.